# cairoでPNG画像を90, 180, 270度回転して保存したい

Tags: linux, c

都合によりImageMagickは使用できません。C言語で実装する必要があります。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834243/rotate-and-save-png-image-using-cairo

本家の方で似た質問があったので試してみたのですが、回転後の画像はなぜか回転前と全く同じでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントより:

> ただ、このサンプルは縦横の解像度が同じ場合しか期待通りにならないですね。ペイントアプリで90度回転させたような見た目にするのは難しいでしょうか？

```
dest = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height);
```

なので、回転前とサイズが変わっていない場合にしか対応できていないのでしょう。

「ペイントアプリ」を知りませんが、以下でいかがでしょうか?
katsuko さんの回答を元に手を加えてみました。

```
#include <cairo.h>

/* 90, 180, 270 */
#define DEGREE 270

int main()
{
    cairo_surface_t *source;
    cairo_surface_t *dest;
    cairo_t *cr;
    int width, height;

    source = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png("source.png");
    width = cairo_image_surface_get_width(source);
    height = cairo_image_surface_get_height(source);
#if DEGREE == 180
    dest = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height);
#else
    dest = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, height, width);
#endif
    cr = cairo_create(dest);
#if DEGREE == 90
    cairo_translate(cr, height, 0);
    cairo_rotate(cr, 3.14159 / 2.0);
#elif DEGREE == 180
    cairo_translate(cr, width, height);
    cairo_rotate(cr, 3.14159);
#else
    cairo_translate(cr, 0, width);
    cairo_rotate(cr, 3.14159 / -2.0);
#endif
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr, source, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint(cr);

    cairo_surface_write_to_png(dest, "result.png");
    cairo_destroy(cr);
    cairo_surface_destroy(dest);
    cairo_surface_destroy(source);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 完全に期待通りの動作になりました。なぜそのようになるのかも、コードから理解することができました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

参考にされている質問・応答に足りていない点といえば、**cairo_surface_write_to_pngにtgtを渡す**点だと思いますが、それを忘れているのでは。
(質問文そのままだとソースイメージを書き出しているので、結果は変わりません)

念の為、こんな感じでできます。

```
#include <cairo.h>

int main()
{
    cairo_surface_t *source;
    cairo_surface_t *dest;
    cairo_t *cr;
    int width, height;

    source = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png("source.png");
    width = cairo_image_surface_get_width(source);
    height = cairo_image_surface_get_height(source);
    dest = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height);
    cr = cairo_create(dest);
    cairo_translate(cr, width / 2.0, height / 2.0);
    cairo_rotate(cr, 3.14159 / 180.0 * 90.0);
    cairo_translate(cr, -width / 2.0, -height / 2.0);
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr, source, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint(cr);

    cairo_surface_write_to_png(dest, "result.png");
    cairo_destroy(cr);
    cairo_surface_destroy(dest);
    cairo_surface_destroy(source);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かにimageをそのままwrite_to_pngしていました。ただ、このサンプルは縦横の解像度が同じ場合しか期待通りにならないですね。ペイントアプリで90度回転させたような見た目にするのは難しいでしょうか？